# Dates in-between two date fields and display all

Tags: date

So I have a table with PatientData: PatientNumber, AdmitDate, and DischargeDate. What I would like is to display something like the following - to give me all the dates from Admit to Discharge.

**Existing table**

```
PatinetNumber    AdmitDate    DischargeDate

**1234**              01/01/22     01/04/22
**9876**              01/01/22     01/01/22
```

**Results**

```
PatinetNumber    AdmitDate    DischargeDate   DateOnLocation

**1234**              01/01/22     01/04/22        01/01/22
**1234**              01/01/22     01/04/22        01/02/22
**1234**              01/01/22     01/04/22        01/03/22
**1234**              01/01/22     01/04/22        01/04/22
**9876**              01/01/22     01/01/22        01/01/22
```

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

solved it - posting for others

```
   SET NOCOUNT ON;  
   
   DECLARE @sql1 NVARCHAR(4000);
   DECLARE @AcctNum NVARCHAR(25), @sDate date, @eDate date, @dDate date
    
   --CREATING TEMP TABLE FOR PATIENTDAYS
   IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..##PATIENTDAYS', 'U') IS NOT NULL
   /*Then it exists*/
   DROP TABLE ##PATIENTDAYS
   CREATE TABLE ##PATIENTDAYS(
    AccountNumber [nvarchar](400) NULL,
    AdmitDate DateTime NULL,
    DischargeDate dateTime NULL,
    PatientDate dateTime NULL
    )
   
     
   DECLARE vendor_cursor CURSOR FOR   
   SELECT Distinct AccountNumber, AdmintDate_Min, DischargetDate_Max 
   FROM DW_reporting.[dbo].[vw_MT_Patient]
   where AccountNumber = '1234'
   ORDER BY AccountNumber;  
     
   OPEN vendor_cursor  
     
   FETCH NEXT FROM vendor_cursor   
   INTO @AcctNum, @sDate, @eDate  
     
   WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0  
   BEGIN  
    
     
       DECLARE product_cursor CURSOR FOR   
        WITH DateRange(DateData) AS 
        (
          SELECT @sDate as Date
          UNION ALL
          SELECT DATEADD(d,1,Date)
          FROM DW_FP.dbo.DimDate 
          WHERE Date >= @sDate and  Date < @eDate 
        )
      SELECT 
      DateData
      FROM DateRange
      OPTION (MAXRECURSION 0)
    
     
       OPEN product_cursor  
       FETCH NEXT FROM product_cursor INTO @dDate   
     
       IF @@FETCH_STATUS <> 0   
           PRINT '         <<None>>'       
     
       WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0  
       BEGIN 
     INSERT INTO ##PATIENTDAYS (AccountNumber,  AdmitDate, DischargeDate, PatientDate)
                             Select  @AcctNum ,  @sDate  ,  @eDate  ,  @dDate
   
    
           FETCH NEXT FROM product_cursor INTO @dDate  
           END  
     
       CLOSE product_cursor  
       DEALLOCATE product_cursor  
           -- Get the next Date.  
       FETCH NEXT FROM vendor_cursor   
       INTO @AcctNum, @sDate, @eDate   
   END   
   CLOSE vendor_cursor;  
   DEALLOCATE vendor_cursor; 
   
     Select A.* , PD.*
     FROM DW_reporting.[dbo].[vw_MT_Patient] A
     LEFT JOIN ##PATIENTDAYS PD on PD.AccountNumber COLLATE Latin1_General_CS_AS = A.AccountNumber COLLATE Latin1_General_CS_AS
     where A.AccountNumber = '1234'
   
     
   DROP TABLE ##PATIENTDAYS;
```